# Does classification report on sklearn require same length for both input x and y?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

I'm getting an error with sklearn classification report.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-6a63be1ce4c8> in <module>
----> 1 classification_report(y_test, predictions)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py in classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, target_names, sample_weight, digits, output_dict)
   1522     """
   1523 
-> 1524     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
   1525 
   1526     labels_given = True

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     69     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     70     """
---> 71     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     72     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     73     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    233     if len(uniques) > 1:
    234         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 235                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    236 
    237 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [360, 144]
```

This is the only thing I'm passing in, and y_test.shape is (360,) and predictions.shape is (144,).

`classification_report(y_test, predictions)`

Do they need to be the same length? (I'm assuming so because of that second stack trace).. If so, how can the length of X and Y can be the same when you split your data? Wouldn't they have different length always?

Comment: you answered your own question: yes they need to be equal. for your second question, you need to split the x and y in equal sizes

Comment: wouldn't that be biased though? usually when you train/split, you'd do 80/20, so how can you have the equal length of test and prediction? How would I actually pick out values from y_test to match predictions?

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept and upvote the answer? If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's a bit of a misunderstanding here about the stats/ML data splitting framework.

Like you suspected, `y_test` and `pred` need to be the same length—let's call it *k*. Why? Because we need there to be *k* testing examples ((*x*, *y*) pairs) to test the model. `X_test` and `y_test` are each *k* entries long. (Each entry *x* in `X_test` may have several features, but it counts as one record.) For each *x* in `X_test`, we make a prediction about its label. Then, to compute a metric like classification accuracy, we compare the predicted label to the true label for *each* testing example.

> If so, how can the length of X and Y can be the same when you split your data?

Peek at the API of [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). You'd call it something like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

What this shows is that `X_test` and `y_test` will have the same number of records in them—they'll always be the same shape, by design. Then for each entry in `X_test`, you make a prediction using your model. It'll be paired with the corresponding entry in `y_test`, and that's how you can compute your classification score.